# Delphi Berlin 10.1 FireDac For OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

I have Fire-Monkey application on Delphi. App was created few years before, i don't know the version of XE it was used. I use Delphi Berlin 10.1

I need to manage possibility to run app on OS X. Application contains FireDac and it can't build for OS X.

I have the next output:

```
[dccosx Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'FireDACDb2Driver' not found
```

I was trying to create other simple application for OS X. And i've got it. All steps are needed to deploy to OS X are included here.

I've read article: [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_from_a_Multi-Device_Application_on_Desktop_Platforms)
But when i test connection i have password error exception. 
Any idea?

Comment: You need to use [FireDAC ODBC bridge driver](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Connect_to_ODBC_Data_Source_(FireDAC)#OS_X_Client_Software) (for Delphi Berlin) as [FireDAC supports natively](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Databases_(FireDAC)) only 32-bit and 64-bit Windows drivers. Did you do follow that?

Comment: I didn't. Okay, thank you, i will google about this today. And give anwer to you.

Or if you can write to me step-by-step instruction please

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, i will try by myself. thank you anyway.

Comment: Vicoria, i'm reading articles you gave me. Why are you talking about FireDAC ODBC br dr, as see in the next link there they say, i need 

"TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink,

FireDAC.Phys.SQLite "
for OSX

Comment: Where? I've linked to OS X Client Software topic (which links to UnixODBC driver) and a summary table showing which platforms are supported for which DBMS'. I'd say that the point is to install UnixODBC driver and connect through ODBC Data Source.

Comment: The second link you gave. Scroll to bottom of the table. There will be drivers for SQLite with platforms they created for

Comment: Anyway, i'm going to try ODBC. Check please what i say, if you have time

Comment: Why do you focus on SQLite? You've reported error about `FireDACDb2Driver` which relates to DB2. Hence my comments are about DB2.

Comment: FDConnector uses sqllite driver, so i talk about this=)

Comment: Hm, then why did you get the error saying `FireDACDb2Driver`? That Db2 sounds like you're having driver link for IMB DB2 included somewhere in your project.

Comment: So, i've solved that by deleting this package from search list. 
I've even deployed on OS X. But get Error unable to open database on osx.